# how to show text area on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
</html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#popup").click(function(){
   // pop up a text area and I want to store value of textarea in a variable.
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="area" style="display:none"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="popup" value="OK">
</body>
</html>
```

How to POPUP a text area on a button click?

Comment: look on this example using modal dialog http://jsfiddle.net/xRugN/

Answer (score 7):

```
var textarea = $('#area');
$("#popup").click(function(){

   // To show it
   textarea.show();

});

// To get the value
var value = textarea.val();
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to attach the function to the click event.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of obtaining `value` is here. The user won't even have had a chance to write into the textarea yet.

Comment: As a complete aside, I usually recommend prepending the names of jQuery object variables with a `$` for distinction. So `var $textarea = $('#area');` Of course, this is largely up to personal taste.

Comment: @alex: Seems to me that, if anything, he wanted to pop up a textarea, wait for input into it, have the user press some 'OK' button then store the result in a variable.

Comment: @Tomalak - plus one on your comment for prepending jQuery objects with `$`. It would be so much easier to read code if everyone did this!

Comment: (or if you have a fundamental objection to prefixing with `$` something like `jq_` would work)

Comment: @alex: My point is that you are obtaining that value immediately after setting the event handler. Seems unlikely that the user has had a chance to write in it yet!

Comment: @alex: "The last thing that really irks me with the $ prefix is that it makes JavaScript variables look like PHP variables (or Perl)." I don't really understand this. You could write a function called "dir" and then moan that it makes your code look like MS DOS.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use `$("#area").show()` to display the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, use the show method:

```
$('#area').show();
```

You can also control the speed of the animation:

```
$('#area').show("slow");
$('#area').show("fast");
```

Or you can specify an exact time in milliseconds. Here's the official documentation:

[jQuery Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)