# open a text area on click of a button - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/E9XVr/53/

Note: I think this is a duplicate of this question: [how to show text area on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814588/how-to-show-text-area-on-button-click) However, the OP of that question never followed up and I don't think any of the answers actually answer the question. I think Tomalak's comment on that question

> Seems to me that, if anything, he wanted to pop up a textarea, wait for input into it, have the user press some 'OK' button then store the result in a variable.

Pretty much sums it up.

When the user clicks a button, I would like a text area to open in which the user can enter some text click an OK button and then the text area will close.

I don't want a dialog box, it's too intrusive, I want just a plain simple textarea or similar to open so that the top left of the text area is positioned at the bottom left of the button.

Thanks!

```
<span style="width:20px;height:20px" class="remarkButton"></span>

$(".remarkButton").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil" }, text: false }).click(function () {
       $(...something to show text area...).data("$clickedButton",$(this));
});

//called when the OK button on the text area is clicked
function saveRemark($referenceToTextArea)
{
$referenceToTextArea.data("$clickedButton").data("remark",$referenceToTextArea.text());
}
```

[image]

Comment: So like the "add comment" feature on StackOverflow? Click a button, a textarea comes magically into existence, and then closes (perhaps changing something elsewhere) when a button is pressed?

Comment: @lonesomeday, but, I want it to appear OVER whatever else is there. It's going to be in a grid, so I don't want everything moving around. Proly should have mentioned that part.

Comment: Wait, do you want a modal? I assumed not, since you said a dialog was too intrusive, and a modal is almost as intrusive as a dialog.

Comment: no it does not have to be modal. I guess it could be described as a non-model dialog that opens underneath the button, but doesn't have any of that extra baggage. Just a text area, and a small simple OK button, not border, header, or something else. It would close via a "close" button or clicking outside of the text area.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, communication skills was never my #1 subject :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've knocked something up very quickly -- it doesn't exactly match your specifications, but it's something similar.  [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9XVr/).

The Javascript:

```
$('#foo').click(function() { // the button - could be a class selector instead
    var button = $(this),
        commentField = $('<textarea/>'); // create a textarea element

    commentField
        .css({
            position: 'absolute', 
            width: 200,          // textbox 200px by 100px
            height: 100,
            // position the textarea directly over the button
            left: button.offset().left + (button.outerWidth() / 2) - 100,
            top: button.offset().top + (button.outerHeight() / 2) - 50
        })
        // set the textarea's value to be the saved content, or a default if there is no saved content
        .val(button.data('textContent') || 'This is my comment field\'s text')
        // set up a keypress handler on the textarea
        .keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which === 13) { // if it's the enter button
                e.preventDefault(); // ignore the line break
                button.data('textContent', this.value); // save the content to the button
                $(this).remove(); // remove the textarea
            }
        })
        .appendTo(document.body); // add the textarea to the document
});
```

The main difference to the specification is that the textarea closes when you press "enter", not on clicking a button. It wouldn't be hard to modify if that's what you want.

Comment: I like the enter idea! I think i'll see if I can make it close on either enter or an OK button or a cancel button. That looks like it should work!

Comment: @kraico626 You'd need to create a container element (probably a `div`) and put the textarea and the buttons in that, then insert the `div` into the document, appropriately styled.  It should be reasonably clear how to do that from the code posted.

Comment: @lonesomeday do you think passing a reference of the textarea to the buttons and having the buttons onclick close the textarea is a good idea? Also any ideas for making it close with "cancel" functionality when clicking outside of the textarea?

Comment: ugh, as soon as I wrap a div around it I loose that nice clean look of the text area, with the option to expand it... http://jsfiddle.net/E9XVr/13/

Comment: @kraico626 I've done a little more with the jsFiddle -- [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/E9XVr/25/).

Comment: @lonesomeday - I like it. I made some additional changes and I think it works great! http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/E9XVr/48/ You can open more than one at a time from different buttons, but only one from any one button, clicking outside closes them all, clicking cancel or ok closes only that one. This should work great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you'll want something like this:

```
<button id="showarea" name="showarea" type="button" value="Show Textarea" />
<textarea id="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
<button id="textarea-ok" name="ok" type="button" value="Ok" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#textarea, #textarea-ok").hide(); // or you can have hidden w/ CSS
    $("#showarea").click(function(){
        $("#textarea").show();
    });
    $("#textarea-ok").click(function(){
        $("#textarea").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Note that you'll need to define the CSS accordingly as you prefer.

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more clear, see my comment above, I want it to appear above over else on the page, and this is going to be in a grid, I need to use classes not ids and pass a reference of the clicked button to the text area so I know what button to save the remark to.

Comment: Okay, I assume by "appear above over else on the page," you mean a modal. I'll update my answer in a minute to hopefully address your concerns.

Comment: OK maybe I don't know the definition of modal. I always took modal to mean you couldn't click anywhere else, not that it appeared above everything else.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry if I confounded the two concepts (modal and dialog). But, I'm still confused. Are you looking for a jQuery-based dialog (such as http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), or something different?

Comment: Please see my rough image... above (thanks for bearing with me :-P)

Comment: If lonesomeday has helped you out more than I did, please go ahead and accept his answer. Sorry for the miscommunication! ;)

Comment: @Josh - the communication issue was most certainly my fault! I appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<button id="showarea" name="showarea" type="button" value="Show Textarea" />
<textarea id="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
<button id="textarea-ok" name="ok" type="button" value="Ok" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#textarea, #textarea-ok").hide(); // or you can have hidden w/ CSS
$("#showarea").click(function(){
      $("#textarea").fadeIn(4000);
});
$("#textarea-ok").click(function(){
      $("#textarea").fadeOut(4000);
});
```

It clears the space also so it looks like new textarea created and removed